# In Flutter/Dart, using async function to assign values, will the variable using the old pointed instance if it's changed?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

The situation is hard to describe, please see the following code:

Example A

```
  class DataStructure {
      String imageURL;
  }

  var _a = DataStructure();
  var _b = DataStructure();
  var _original_a = _a;
  var _original_b = _b;

  _uploadImg(PickedFile image) async {
    setState(() {
      _imgPath = image.path;
    });
    _a.imageURL = await _upload(_imgPath);
    _a = _b; // assign the _a pointing to another data instance(The assignment here is just an example, maybe it's triggered by user's input. No matter how it's triggered, it happened before the _upload function finished.)
  }
```

Example B

```
  class DataStructure {
      String imageURL;
  }

  var _a = DataStructure();
  var _b = DataStructure();
  var _original_a = _a;
  var _original_b = _b;

  _uploadImg(PickedFile image) async {
    setState(() {
      _imgPath = image.path;
    });
    var resultVal = _upload(_imgPath);
    resultVal.then((val){
      _a.imageURL = val;
    });
    _a = _b; // assign the _a pointing to another data instance(The assignment here is just an example, maybe it's triggered by user's input. No matter how it's triggered, it happened before the _upload function finished.)
  }
```

In both examples, will the returned value assigned to `_original_a.imageURL` or `_original_.imageURL`? The proper goal here is to assign it to `_original_a.imageURL`.

I've tested it using a similar and simpler dart example using `sleep()`(because the example codes are hard to test in production environment). I think in both cases the result will be assigned to `_original_a.imageURL`. But I'm not 100% sure that my test is correct, nor do I understand what actually happened behind the hood. Could someone help me please?

In my understanding, in the 1st example, because there's a `await` keyword,  so the program will wait for `_uploade()` function to run. And only after the result of _upload() is assigned to _a.imageURL, the program will execute _a = _b.

I'm not sure what happens In the 2nd example. Since there's no `await` keyword, will the program execute `_a = _b` before the `_upload()` function finished?

Comment: Oh really sorry, `_currentItem` is a typo. It should be `_a`. Updated the question. In the first example, the `await` call makes sure the `_a = _b` happens after the assignment. I think this is what happens that makes sure `data[0].imageURL` gets the result. But I'm not sure about the 2nd example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made some tests again, and here's my conclusion to this quesiont: no, it does not use the old pointed instance.

Assuming that `_upload()` will return a `Future` of string `'abc'`.

In example A, `_original_a.imageURL` has the new value `'abc'`, `_original_a.imageURL` has its original value(`null` in this example.)

In example B, `_original_a.imageURL` has its original value, but `_original_b.imageURL` has the new value `'abc'`.

Why?

`await` keyword stops the execution and wait for the async function to return a value in example A. In example B, since there's no `await` keyword, the `_a = _b;` line is executed immediately, and it's before the execution of `_a.imageURL = val;`. When the `_upload()` is finished after some time, the part within `then` block will be executed. However at this point, the `_a` pointer has already been changed to pointing another instance(same with `_b` and `_original_b`). So the `'abc'` is assigned to `'_original_b'` now.

Comment: Example B is *undefined behavior*. You can never truly predict the result of it.